# textview is not obeying resource fontfamily

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts, android-typeface

I am using fonttype defined this way, and android studio's layout design view is showing the string/textview in the weathericon font.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFragThird"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/weathericons"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But,when I am running this piece of code:

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragThird);
//        Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), R.font.weathericons);
//        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        tv.setText("&#xf0eb;");//getArguments().getString("msg"));

return v;
}
```

I am just getting the text in normal font. I have tried both defining the fontfamily in layout and typeface in java, and none of them are working.

what I am missing?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

Comment: Please stop referring old codes. Font should go inside res, not in assets. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Comment: just trying to help bud. no need to accuse me of always giving out "old" code. which font are you using? can i download it somewhere? i tested it with a font from dafont.com and it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry if I sound accusing. But I am a bit frustrated with this scenario: for a new programmer like me, search any thing for android and there is 100s of solutions, you learn it, only to fond its deprecated. 
I am using weather-icons : http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/

Comment: i personally think the phone doesn't know how to route the items to characters. for example, with the custom font I used, i typed in hello! as the setText and hello was changed, but the ! wasnt. so Id imagine that android ois having a hard time converting text into weather icons.

Comment: thats not true, if I don't put anything from the fragment and just use the same font in layout, android can show this.

Answer (score 1):

As it's mentioned here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml, **custom font** using **fontFamily**, needs **API >= 26**.

So change **TextView** tag to **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView** tag (if you use API < 26).

I had this problem and i came across above link and did above change and my problem is solved and i hope, it solves yours (if it has not been solved yet) and others.

**Update:**

As **RobCo** commented, if you can change to **AppCompatActivity**, you don't need above change. It's mentioned here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView

Comment: Any TextView in xml will automatically be replaced with an AppCompatTextView when inflated from xml, if you use an AppCompatActivity and AppCompat theme.